# Accessing local variable in wobblyMethod()

Tags: java, arrays, variables, local

I'm stumped on how to access the array a from inside the wobblyMethod() for my exception. I need a.length to finish the question. I've outlined my problems

[image]

My code is below:

```
public String wobblyMethodHandler(){

try{
    wobblyMethod();
    String b = "No exception";
    return b;
} 
catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
    String h = "Array index " + " out of bounds!";
    return h;
}
catch(Exception e){
    String g = "Exception!";
    return g;
}
}
```

How do I get the length of that array?

Comment: The exception as a method `getMessage()`. Try its return value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the length of the array you want, it's the invalid cell that you're trying to access (it's just co-incidence that the value "3" is also the length of the array).  Change your code to:-

```
...
catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
    String h = "Array index " + e.getMessage() + " out of bounds!";
    return h;
}
...
```

Comment: For `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, `getMessage()` returns the faulty index alone, nothing else .

Comment: So the only thing I'm defining in this question is the wobblyMethodHandler(). The wobblyMethod() has already been given so I'm not able to edit it.

Comment: If the 3 is hard-coded in the question, just change your line to `String h = "Array index 3 out of bounds!";`.

Comment: My code is supposed to handle more examples than only the 3. There are more examples of test cases at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you! I just had to use the e.getMessage properly in my first catch statement. This is what solved it 

`catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){

    String h = e.getMessage();

    return "Array index " + h + " is out of bounds!";

}`

Comment: @Steve Smith I think the key is that the wobblyMethod is given by someone else and changes along the task. So thecyclax shall learn about e.getMessage() and how to get infos from it - not how to write a new exception

Comment: @M.Schwarzer-Haverbier Yes! My problem was that I didn't know how to use the e.getMessage()

Answer (score 0):

Tip: use the parameter e, e.getMessage(), the index should be available there somewhere.

```
catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
    String h = "Array index " + " out of bounds!";
    return h;
}
```